# Detecting clicks inside a div using wildcards in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got to this so far using the jQuery docs

```
$('[class^="layout"] > ("*")').click(function(e) {
    alert("inside");
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is detecting whether something inside a div which has a class beginning with the name 'layout' is clicked and returning that parent div's class.

For context an example div would be something like

```
<div class="builder_body" id="the_content">
    <div class="layout_2cwlh_header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="layout_2cwlh_wrapper">
        <div class="layout_2cwlh_content">
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <p>sometext</p>
        </div>
        <div class="layout_2cwlh_sidebar">
            <h1>Sidebar</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I click on anything like a h1/p or anything inside a div, I need to return the parent div's class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('[class^="layout"]').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // added to prevent a new alert every
                         // time the click bubbles to a new parent
    alert($(this).closest('div[id]').attr('id'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fCTve/).

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple actually:

```
$('[class^="layout"]').click(function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).parent;
    // do something with the parent.prop('class');
});
```